# Firebase my notification not show me the recived time hour

Tags: java, android, notifications

when I receive the notifications, it comes without time, never showing me hour, find the below attached code.

This is my notification code

```
public void showBigNotification(String title, String message, String url, Intent intent) {
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mCtx,
                        ID_BIG_NOTIFICATION,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(getBitmapFromURL(url));
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);
        Notification notification;
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(ID_BIG_NOTIFICATION, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace **0** with `System.currentTimeMillis()` in .setWhen() function.

```
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
```